# How do you replace regex end-of-line with string?

Tags: python, regex

I have a for loop that produces a variable `current_out_dir`, sometimes the variable will have a `/.` at the end of the line (that is `/.$`) I want to replace `/.$` with `/$`. Currently I have `.replace('/.','/')`, but this would replace hidden directories that start with `.` as well. e.g. `/home/.log/file.txt`

I've looked into `re.sub()` but I can't figure out how to apply it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dot will match any character not of newline character. So you need to escape the dot to match a literal dot.

```
re.sub(r'(?<=/)\.$', r'', string)
```

Comment: In terms of a variable rather than a string, could I do `current_out dir = re.sub(r'(?<=/)\.$', r'\/', current_out_dir)` Your `r''` would remove the string entirely instead of replace it with `/`, correct?

Comment: no , it removes the last dot which was just after to `/` with an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

```
/\.(?=$)
```

Try this.This should work for you.This uses a positive lookahead to assert end of string.

Answer (score 0):

The question was about using regex, but I've come up with a more pythonic solution to the problem.

```
if os.path.split(current_out_dir)[1] == '.':
    current_out_dir = os.path.split(current_out_dir)[0]
```